# NodeJS + MySQL connects from localhost, but not heroku

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku

I've got a simple web app that needs to connect to my database. I created a user called public which can only SELECT from the database.

Everything works perfectly fine from localhost. I deployed the app on Heroku, and it gives me the following error:

> 2016-10-18T00:17:59.282323+00:00 app[web.1]: Couldn't connect :(  Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
>   2016-10-18T00:17:59.282562+00:00 app[web.1]: Something went wrong... Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

```
app.get("/", function(request, response){
    response.render("index");
});

// request for quotes is received
app.get("/get", function(req, res){

    // open a connection to the database
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        connectionLimit: 100,
        host: "my-test-database.c3j6vph7cyv2.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
        user: "public",
        password:"helloworld",
        database:"quotes"
    });

    // connect to the database
    connection.connect(function(error){
        if(error){
            console.log("Couldn't connect :(  " + error);
        } else {
            console.log("Connected successfully~!");
        }    
    });

    // retrieve quotes from database
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM Quotes", function(error, rows, fields){
       if (error) {
           console.log("Something went wrong... " + error);
           res.end();
       } else {
          res.jsonp({"quotes": rows});
       }
    });

    connection.end();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you need to authorize your Heroku dynos to access RDS (from the url in your code I assume you are using it). Check [this link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/amazon-rds#authorizing-access-to-rds-instance) for the steps